# Is there a webapp for VoIP?

Tags: voip

I'm looking for a good webvapp that will enable hosting a SIP proxy. Maybe something that lets me route and setup dialins and dialouts around the world. Does such a solution exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [JaJah Web](http://www.jajah.com/products/web/)
- [GizmoCall](https://www.gizmocall.com/gc/app?class=GizmoCall&proc=gcStart)
- [Raketu](http://www.raketu.com/en/RakOutWeb.php)

Comment: gizmocall seems to be down.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few more:

- http://www.openvbx.org
- http://ringio.com
- http://phonebooth.com